# How to invert numpy.where (np.where) function

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, where-clause, indices

I frequently use the numpy.where function to gather a tuple of indices of a matrix having some property.  For example

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(3,3)
>>> X
array([[ 0.51035326,  0.41536004,  0.37821622],
   [ 0.32285063,  0.29847402,  0.82969935],
   [ 0.74340225,  0.51553363,  0.22528989]])
>>> ix = np.where(X > 0.5)
>>> ix
(array([0, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 2, 0, 1]))
```

ix is now a tuple of ndarray objects that contain the row and column indices, whereas the sub-expression X>0.5 contains a single boolean matrix indicating which cells had the >0.5 property.  Each representation has its own advantages.

What is the best way to take ix object and convert it back to the boolean form later when it is desired?   For example

```
G = np.zeros(X.shape,dtype=np.bool)
>>> G[ix] = True
```

Is there a one-liner that accomplishes the same thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
mask = np.zeros(X.shape, dtype='bool')
mask[ix] = True
```

but if it's something simple like `X > 0`, you're probably better off doing `mask = X > 0` unless `mask` is very sparse or you no longer have a reference to `X`.

Answer (score 4):

```
mask = X > 0
imask = np.logical_not(mask)
```

For example

Edit: Sorry for being so concise before. Shouldn't be answering things on the phone :P

As I noted in the example, it's better to just invert the boolean mask. Much more efficient/easier than going back from the result of `where`.

Answer (score 4):

The bottom of the `np.where` docstring suggests to use `np.in1d` for this.

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 6])
>>> indices = np.where(x % 3 == 1)[0]
>>> indices
array([0, 2, 3, 5])
>>> np.in1d(np.arange(len(x)), indices)
array([ True, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

(While this is a nice one-liner, it is a lot slower than @Bi Rico's solution.)